# c# add am/pm to my (string)date value automatically

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have a datagridview will display the date value which extracted from database (mysql), see the pic
[image]

the value in database is (datatype is datetime)

2018-02-28 00:00:00 
2017-02-02 00:00:00

in program code i set the value using this

```
dataObj.special_from_date = (string)productData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["special_from_date"].ToString();
dataObj.special_to_date = (string)productData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["special_to_date"].ToString();
```

Except datagridview cell, in textfield it also display the value with am/pm 上午/下午 text, anyone know what is the reason?

-------------------------update------------------------------

```
DateTime sfd = DateTime.Now;
    if (productData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["special_from_date"].ToString() != "") {
    //DateTime sfd = DateTime.TryParseExact(productData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["special_from_date"].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show("tet");
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(productData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["special_from_date"].ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out sfd))
       {
                            // use d
        MessageBox.Show(sfd.ToString());
       }
    }
```

---

```
    public DataSet selectConnect(MySqlCommand cmd)
    {

        try
        {

            adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            ds = new DataSet();

            cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adapter.Fill(ds);

            adapter.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Show any error message.
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        return ds;

    } //connect
```

---

```
        dao dao = dao.GetInstance;
        databaseConnection = dao.connect();
        sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, databaseConnection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();


        databaseConnection.Open();
        ds = dao.selectConnect(sqlCmd);
        List<productData> products = dao.getProducts(ds);
        productData product = products.First();
```

---

Answer (score 0):

It is because localization applied on your result automatically. You can format your date time at the time of converting to string which helps you to avoid this.

dataObj.special_from_date = productData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["special_from_date"].ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

Comment: can you tell me what is the exact error message please?

Comment: productData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["special_from_date"] is string, not datetime, so, there is not oString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss") method exists

Comment: only way to do is replace am/pm string?

Comment: are you using data adapter to fill the data? try to add the columns with type before you populate the data to the data table. it will helps. 

productData.Tables[0].Columns.Add("special_from_date", typeof(datetime));

Comment: my code auto add the columns                 adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                adapter.Fill(ds);

Comment: You can use date_format mysql function. You can specify which format you need there. for more information about date_format function you can visit the following link https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp